# Ubuntu 18.10 broken and crispy font rendering issues

Tags: fonts, screen, display-resolution

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10 and after upgrading, the fonts are all messed up.

I am using Acer Aspire E15 Laptop with resolution of 1920x1080p with aspect ratio of 16:9. The fonts are all default.

Font Manager:

[image: Font-manager page screenshot here.]

Sample:

[image: Chrome sample font display]

Comment: status please...

Comment: Hey, i fixed it by installing XFCE.

Comment: That really isn't the correct fix. You've downgraded your OS from gdm3 to XFCE. Hadn't you tried my answer, shown below?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `Font Manager` didn't help the situation much. Use the `Tweaks`application, and make the settings look like this...

[image]